# BootstrapDialog not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use BootstrapDialog.show, but something is wrong with my code.

This is my code:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/stylesheets/screen/bootstrap-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/lib/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>

//Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(json.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .style("fill", "steelblue")
            .on("mouseover",mouseover)
            .on("mouseout", mouseout)
            .on("click", function(){
                BootstrapDialog.show({
                    title: 'Users:',
                    message: "users' links",
                    draggable: true
                });
            });
```

When I click on the object, the page becomes way too darker than it should, and the draggable is not working at all.
Does anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well your JS Code is first of all incomplete, and secondly we don't see the actual code. So we can't really help you unless you provide more info.

Comment: yeah please provide `HTML` code also

Comment: I am using d3 graph and all the code is the JS.

Comment: That is the only place I am using something related to BootstrapDialog if it helps @brance